# Cargar datos en la misma pagina en php

Tags: php, mysql

espero me puedan apoyar a resolver un problema que me surgió.
Resulta que tengo un formulario en una pagina php, ahí mismo ejecuto una consulta a mi base de datos y ahí mismo cargo los datos del resultado de la consulta y le agregue la paginacion. Hasta ahí todo bien.
El problema viene cuando presiono un botón de la paginación, al parecer se vuelve a refrescar la pagina. La consulta desaparece.
A que se deberá, que estoy haciendo mal.
Gracias.

Comment: Por favor añade el código que te está dando problemas. No sabemos cómo estás construyendo la paginación, a qué controlador lleva cada uno de los botones, si mandas algún valor nuevo para consultar otra vez en la BBDD ...

Comment: A tu pregunta agrégale el código para ver que puede estar mal. Está difícil saber qué puede estar mal sin una referencia.